# Topology manager not installed: Authorization denied

Tags: web8.5, installation

I am trying to run the Content Manager install for SDL Web 8.5, but I'm getting repeated failures to install the topology manager. By repeated, I mean that I've (more than once!) attempted a complete uninstall and re-install. (I've also tried a repair.) When it reaches the topology manager, I get this message: "Authorization has been denied for this request".

[image: SDL Web installer failing]

> I've looked in the logging, and I can see that various files are reported to give problems: here's an example.
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:05.630 [7620]: Assembly Install: Entering CAssemblyCache::UninstallAssembly(0, policy.8.5.Tridion.TopologyManager.Client,fileVersion="8.5.0.466",version="8.5.0.466",culture="neutral",publicKeyToken="DDFC895746E5EE6B",processorArchitecture="MSIL")
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:05.864 [7620]: Assembly Install: Failing with hr=80070005 at RemoveDirectoryAndChildren, line 393
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:05.864 [7620]: Detailed info about C:\Windows\assembly\temp\3Q7OPMJ17G\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.dll
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:05.864 [7620]:    File attributes: 00000080
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:06.007 [7620]:    Restart Manager Info: 5 entries
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:06.007 [7620]:        App[0]: (7236) SDL Web Content Manager Service Host (TcmServiceHost), type = 3
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:06.007 [7620]:        App[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICbM7.png): (8136) SDL Web Content Manager Workflow Agent (TCMWorkflow), type = 3
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:06.007 [7620]:        App[2]: (7180) SDL Web Content Manager Search Indexer (TcmSearchIndexer), type = 3
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:06.007 [7620]:        App[3]: (7016) SDL Web Content Manager Batch Processor (TcmBatchProcessor), type = 3
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:06.008 [7620]:        App[4]: (7292) SDL Web Content Manager Publisher (TcmPublisher), type = 3
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:06.008 [7620]:    Security info:
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:06.008 [7620]:        Owner: S-1-5-18
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:06.008 [7620]:        Group: S-1-5-18
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:06.008 [7620]:        DACL information: 5 entries:
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:06.008 [7620]:        ACE[0]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001f01ff, SID = S-1-5-18
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:06.008 [7620]:        ACE[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICbM7.png): Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001f01ff, SID = S-1-5-32-544
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:06.008 [7620]:        ACE[2]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001200a9, SID = S-1-5-32-545
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:06.009 [7620]:        ACE[3]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001200a9, SID = S-1-15-2-1
>
> 09/24/2017 10:07:06.009 [7620]:        ACE[4]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001200a9, SID = S-1-15-2-2

What can be causing this? How can I solve it? Are there any alternative approaches: perhaps a manual install of this component. If so, how would I go about it? Is there other logging I could look at that might help, or can I enable extra logging?

EDIT:

I've also found this message in the logs. It seems to match the message in the popup pretty well:

> Begin CreateCMEntityExecute
>
> CreateCMEntity: Delete user account _Tridion_Temp_User_.
>
> CreateCMEntity: Create user account _Tridion_Temp_User_.
>
> CreateCMEntity: Add user account _Tridion_Temp_User_ to group WEB85\Topology Manager Administrators.
>
> Execute application 'net' with arguments 'localgroup "Topology Manager Administrators" "_Tridion_Temp_User_" /add'
>
> CreateCMEntity: result '0'
>
> CreateCMEntity: Add user account _Tridion_Temp_User_ to group S-1-5-32-544.
>
> Execute application 'net' with arguments 'localgroup "Administrators" "_Tridion_Temp_User_" /add'
>
> CreateCMEntity: result '0'
>
> CreateCMEntity: Log on as user _Tridion_Temp_User_.
>
> Website with id '1' is started
>
> Website with id '4' is started
>
> CreateCMEntity: Run PS command: Add-TtmCmEnvironment -Id 'Tridioncm_local' -CoreServiceRootUrl 'net.tcp://localhost:2660' -WebsiteRootUrl 'http://sdlweb:81' -AuthenticationType 'Windows' -UserName 'CRONINTECH\tridionsys' -Password '****' -TtmServiceUrl 'http://topman:82/ttm201601'.
>
> CreateCMEntity: error Authorization has been denied for this request.
>
> MSI (s) (08!30) [21:30:07:769]: Product: SDL Web Topology Manager -- Authorization has been denied for this request.
>
> Authorization has been denied for this request.
>
> CreateCMEntity: Delete user account _Tridion_Temp_User_.
>
> CustomAction CreateCMEntityExecute returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)

I suspect that the problem is in part that the server is a domain controller. On the other hand, that should work, right? I deleted my local tridionsys account, but that didn't help.

Comment: The error message in the log hints at a file permissions issue in the GAC. Did you try running procmon.exe to get this confirmed?

Comment: I've spent some time with procmon. The install generates a LOT of activity. Still need to refine my filters to get anything useful.

Comment: What kind of permissions are you running the installer as? Has it already installed the Topology Manager Groups? If so - add your user to the group and try again - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTw3X.png

Comment: Try using a procmon filter on `Path contains policy.8.5.Tridion.TopologyManager`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I suspected based on the logging, it seems that the problem (at least indirectly) was that the server was a domain controller. This was the default setup for Windows Server, but I don't really need a DC, as the machine in question is just my own Tridion research image.

I removed Active Directory Domain services, and a few other things like DNS and Certificate server that were necessary to get the DC demoted and removed. After that, the Tridion CM installer worked like a charm, and I now appear to have a working Topology manager.

I think it's probably reasonable to want to run Tridion on a server that hosts a Domain Controller. I don't need to do it myself, but I can imagine scenarios where it would make sense. The exact problem I had is not completely clear, but I think it had something to do with putting restricted local accounts like NETWORK SERVICE into a domain group. I have no hard evidence, but it seems a reasonable interpretation of the error messages.

Is it a product issue? I can't really say. Perhaps someone at SDL has an opinion.

Comment: Although it is not clear to me why installation on a DC would fail, it is considered bad practice to install applications on a DC (for example, see http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server/q-what-software-and-roles-are-ok-install-domain-controller-dc ).  Which scenarios do you imagine?

Comment: My guess is that on a DC, when you create a group, it's a domain group. Guessing though. The most obvious scenario is the fifth environment... do no biggie.

Comment: What is “the fifth environment”? A stand-alone developer box? Why would you let that be a DC?

Comment: Yes - 5th env is a dev's box. In my case, I was using Windows Server Essentials, which comes out-of-the-box with a DC running. AFAICT it's a supported scenario. Maybe the easiest fix is just to stop supporting it, and update the docs to reflect this. I can't see any huge objections to that.

Answer (score 2):

I think t[his blog](https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=Http-Error-500-InternalServerError-Topology-Install-Failed) can solve your problem

If the above blog is not solving  your problem try to add  `NETWORK SERVICE` account in Administrator group on the server.

Regards
Abhijit Angre

Answer (score 1):

Few things you may try:

- Did you install using "Run As Administrator"
- Can you verify the Database User you have used for Topology manager have appropriate access - may be you can try using the "sa" user while providing information for Topology Manger DB in the installer
- I am sure you have done this, but can you re-check all Pre-Requisite needed and functioning correctly for SDL Web Content Manager

Comment: Indeed - I ran it "As Administrator". The database user seems to be OK. Also - I think the pre-requisites are OK - which is also somewhat backed up by the fact that the installer checks them and doesn't complain.