# SDL Web 8.5 Installation Problem: Error occurred while attempting to communicate with Topology Manager Service

Tags: web8.5, topology-manager, installation

We are installing SDL Web 8.5 with development purposes. The problem is we get this error when running the installer:

[image: error]

The error is:
Error occurred while attempting to communicate with Topology Manager Service at 'http://localhost:92/ttm201601'. The server returned the following response code: 500 (InternalServerError).

We get the same message in the log file.

After that, installation software does a rollback.

This is the extract of the log file:

> Calling custom action
>   CommonCustomActions!CommonCustomActions.CreateCMEntityCustomActions.CreateCMEntityExecute
>   Begin CreateCMEntityExecute CreateCMEntity: Delete user account
>   _Tridion_Temp_User_. CreateCMEntity: Create user account _Tridion_Temp_User_. CreateCMEntity: Add user account _Tridion_Temp_User_ to group SDL85\Topology Manager Administrators. Execute application 'net' with arguments 'localgroup "Topology Manager
>   Administrators" "_Tridion_Temp_User_" /add' CreateCMEntity: result '0'
>   CreateCMEntity: Add user account _Tridion_Temp_User_ to group
>   S-1-5-32-544. Execute application 'net' with arguments 'localgroup
>   "Administradores" "_Tridion_Temp_User_" /add' CreateCMEntity: result
>   '0' CreateCMEntity: Log on as user _Tridion_Temp_User_. Website with
>   id '2' is started Website with id '3' is started CreateCMEntity: Run
>   PS command: Add-TtmCmEnvironment -Id 'Tridioncm_local'
>   -CoreServiceRootUrl 'net.tcp://localhost:2660' -WebsiteRootUrl 'http://SDL85:91' -AuthenticationType 'Windows' -UserName
>   'SDL85\MTSUser' -Password '****' -TtmServiceUrl
>   'http://localhost:92/ttm201601'. CreateCMEntity: error Error occurred
>   while attempting to communicate with Topology Manager Service at
>   'http://localhost:92/ttm201601'. The server returned the following
>   response code: 500 (InternalServerError). MSI (s) (A4!5C)
>   [12:05:14:409]: Product: SDL Web Topology Manager -- Error occurred
>   while attempting to communicate with Topology Manager Service at
>   'http://localhost:92/ttm201601'. The server returned the following
>   response code: 500 (InternalServerError).
>
> Error occurred while attempting to communicate with Topology Manager
>   Service at 'http://localhost:92/ttm201601'. The server returned the
>   following response code: 500 (InternalServerError). CreateCMEntity:
>   Delete user account _Tridion_Temp_User_. CustomAction
>   CreateCMEntityExecute returned actual error code 1603 (note this may
>   not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox) MSI (s)
>   (A4:44) [12:05:21:459]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035  MSI (s)
>   (A4:44) [12:05:21:460]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0 MSI
>   (s) (A4:44) [12:05:21:460]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is
>   0 Action ended 12:05:21: InstallExecuteAgain. Return value 3.

Comment: Please take look into this article https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000005294

Comment: Thanks, we already did that and it didn't work.

Comment: normally, if you get a 500 server error in IIS, there should be a log in the windows event viewer that shows you the actual error that occurred (it should show up as an asp.net warning). This could give you more information on what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved now. It was a bad combination of Windows server roles.

First, we had the Domain Controller Role in our server.
(more information in [Topology manager not installed: Authorization denied](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/17890/topology-manager-not-installed-authorization-denied))

In a different installation, server was not a domain controller but we had a problem with IIS.

Finally we found the right setup for our Windows installation and everything went fine.